# disable past dates and to-date duration to three month

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, date, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have created an application for getting a calendar using angularjs, I have used [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker) plugin for achieving that. The application is working fine but the issue is that I want to disable all the pass dates apart from the current date as well as only three months should be enabled starting from the current date.

Is there any feature like start date and end date for this plugin

Can anyone please help me on this

My working demo is shown in the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0pnyzacx/)**

**Html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">Selected Date: {{ data.embeddedDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd a' }}
        <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.embeddedDate" data-datetimepicker-config="{ startView:'day', minView:'day' }" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker']);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
});
```

Comment: I don't see anything about it in their documentation... you might have to change their source to make it work.  I use this library with bootstrap, it does have it and pretty good options beyond it: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: where we need to change to get that functionality

Comment: You'd have to build it yourself - it appears to be open source on github so you have their source, you could just fork it.

Comment: @Brian that functionality is already there via the `before-render` callback. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a 'before-render' callback that will execute on every render of the datepicker, giving you a range of `DateObject`s appearing the current view. One of the properties of the `DateObject` is `selectable`. Setting that controls if the date can be chosen.

For your scenario it is very easy to implement:

```
$scope.beforeRender = function ($view, $dates, $leftDate, $upDate, $rightDate) {
        var threeMonthsLater = moment().add(3, 'months');
        for(var index=0;index<$dates.length;index++) {
            $dates[index].selectable = moment($dates[index].utcDateValue).isBetween(moment(),threeMonthsLater);            
        }
    }
```

Use version of moment.js greater than 2.9 for `isBetween` support. This library is required for the datepicker anyway.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmf1r8rq/)

Comment: thanks for the answer, actually I want the current date also to be get selected in the calendar